# Deserialize a serialized ArrayList of Custom objects, add an object, and then reserialize

Tags: java, android, arraylist, gson, sharedpreferences

I am trying to store a custom array list of objects for an application I am making with android studios. I need to be able to add new objects to the list whenever the user presses a button. My approach is to first initialize an empty serialized version of the array list with the correct type(catch of the try/ catch). Then to deserialize that array as a temp array list called "RecoTrackGameCollection", then add the new object, and reserialize the array and save it.

The issue I am having is that when I try to add any objects to the "RecoTrackGameCollection" the code fails and runs the catch.

Thank you for taking the time to look at this. If there is anymore information you need please tell me.

```
try {
    //get shared pref
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("SavedGames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //deserilize
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String serialRecoverList = prefs.getString("SavedGames", "");
    Log.wtf("String Recover", serialRecoverList);
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Game>>(){}.getType();
    ArrayList<Game> RecoTrackGameCollection = gson.fromJson(serialRecoverList, type);

    //add game
    RecoTrackGameCollection.add(SearchGameCollection.get(position));

    //reserilize
    Gson NewGson = new Gson();
    String JsonTrakingGames = NewGson.toJson(RecoTrackGameCollection);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString("Games", JsonTrakingGames);
    editor.commit();


    Toast.makeText(mContext , "Game Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (Exception e) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String JsonTrakingGames = gson.toJson(TrackGameCollection);
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("SavedGames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString("Games", JsonTrakingGames);

    editor.commit();

    Toast.makeText(mContext , "iniatlizing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

This is the Game class

```
public class Game {
    String name;
    double price;
    String link;
    //constructor
    Game(String name, double price,String link){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.link = link;

    }

}
```

I believe my error is in the deserilization of the array. In particular this line:

```
ArrayList<Game> RecoTrackGameCollection = gson.fromJson(serialRecoverList, 
type);
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Such as: what is the exception stack trace? And hint: learn about type erasure. That empty list does NOT know which type of objects it is supposed to contain!

Comment: @GhostCat will do, thank you

Comment: Again: please read [mcve]. What is the exception you get? Add the stack trace!

Comment: @GhostCat I have the solution so I wont edit this question, but ill be sure to do it right the next time. Thank you for making an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you've use different key when saving and getting the list.

You can use the following to save the list:

```
private void saveGames(Lis<Game> games) {
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   String json = gson.toJson(games);
   SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("SavedGames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   editor.putString("Games", json);
   editor.commit();
}
```

and the following to get the list:

```
private List<Game> getGames(Context ctx) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  SharedPreferences prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("SavedGames", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  String json = prefs.getString("Games", "");
  if(json.isEmpty()) {
    return new ArrayList<>();
  } else {
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Game>>(){}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
  }

}
```

Comment: @GhostCat: Thank you! I never realize this before. And after further reading the Gson documentation, you're completely correct. I'll update the answer then.

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you so much for your support.